# Changing date on Power BI Graph

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have recently been developing a BI Graph, not important as to what for, however, I have been having some trouble with changing the "Start Date" of the week on the graph. The standard BI Calendar pulls Sun (0) to Sat(6). I am looking to change it to Monday so the image changes to a Mondays date.[image: Issue Here]

I have tried editing the power query to define the first day of week as a Mon `varFirstDayOfWeek Day.Monday` I have tried adding in a new column which finds the date and returns the start of that week. Nothing i do seems to work. If only there was a simple way to change the Power BI Calendar start date.

Comment: Which visual is this and what are you using for the X-axis? Do you have your own Date/Calendar table?

Comment: Apologies for not specifying.
The X axis is fed by a column which has a multitude of dates depending on the date that a certain item is required.

Comment: I think all you need is just a Calculated Column with this

WeekStartDate = 'Date_Table'[Date] - WEEKDAY(Date_Table[Date] , 2) + 1

The + 1  will increment the week number index by 1, so that will it will include upcoming Sunday in that week instead of previous Sunday

Comment: That would just return the start of the week, 

using that information in my graph would then collate all the data into Monday